# $Q(f+g)_*=Q(f_*+g_*)$ (The maps induced by the sum is the sum of induced maps modulo decomposables [Reference request]

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $X, Y$, let's say, homotopy commutative $H$-spaces, $f,g$ maps from $X$ to $Y$.  (Actually we only need $Y$ to be homotopy commutative $H$_space,
but the statement is easier if we also suppose $X$ to be one).  It is not difficult to show that

$Q(f+g)_*=Qf_* +Qg_*$ where $Q$ denotes the module of indecomposables,
and $_*$ denotes, let's say, induced map in mod $p$ ordinary homology.
(Actually any generalized homology works here as long as we have Kunneth isomorphism.)

This can be shown either by directly writing down the two sides
(if we denote $$\Delta (x)= x \otimes 1 +1\otimes x +\Sigma x' \otimes x''$$ then, we have $$(f+g)_*(x)= f_*x +g_*x + \Sigma f_*x' \otimes g_*x''\mbox{ })$$
or by noting that both $_*$ and Q are additive functors.

Now my question is: I have seen this written somewhere, could anyone tell me where I can find a published reference?

This is something completely trivial once you know.  However,

1. it is not so well-known
2. if I hadn't read it some where, then I probably wouldn't have found it on my own
3. it makes the life a lot easier.

To illustrate these points, I can say that I have seen a paper where the author computes
$(f+g)_*$ in a great length then only to pass to the indecomposable quotients.  So the author and the referee of the paper weren't able to come up
with this.

So I really would like to give credit to whoever wrote this fact in a published paper.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this not immediate from working with the dual problem and noting that $Q(f+g)_*$ is dual to $Pf^*$, $Pg^*$, where $P$ is the module of primitives in the mod p cohomology?

Comment: @Tyrone Well, I am not sure considering only elements for which there is no "extra terms" in the diagonal and then dualizing is more "immediate" than quotienting out tje extra terms in the diagonal.

Comment: Note that, since the definition of $f+g$  uses the diagonal and the multiplication in symmetric ways, that the same argument you give also says that $(f+g)_* = f_* + g_*$ on homology primitives.  I used this fact, without comment, in my 2015 J.Topology paper (see Theorem 1.4).  I am sure many people have similarly used this.   If you want a reference, maybe search in Joe Neisendorfer's book, as folks who study finite loop spaces and their decompositions need these sorts of tools.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick.  Unfortunately I couldn't find it in Neisendorfer's book or his papers.